# Property Animaton

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

In the recent days, I plan to write a guide animation, I make use of `viewpager`. but in the second pager, I used the `property Animation`, but it don't show as i image.this is the code.

```
   public class HabitFragmnet extends  BaseFragment {


   private ImageView first;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.habit_layout, null);
    first = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.habit_button);
    startAnimaton();
    return rootView;
}


 @Override
 public void startAnimaton() {
    ValueAnimator firetAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first,"scale",0.0f,1.0f);
    firetAnim.setDuration(1000);
    first.setPivotX(first.getWidth());
    first.setPivotY(first.getHeight());
    first.invalidate();
    firetAnim.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(2));
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.play(firetAnim);
    set.start();
}

  @Override
  public void stopAnimation() {

}
```

who could give me some solution?

Comment: Have you called this "startAnimation()" function?
BTW, there is no "public void startAnimation()" function in View, it only has "public void startAnimation(Animation)". I think you should provide more clear information. Such like the class you overrided its "startAnimation()" function.

Comment: thanks, I use ObjectAnimator , it has a start() function. this can start a animator. Just now, I find the one solution. it is the viewpager problem.the animation shuld start when pager changed.

Comment: @Chatea i update the code. please look at it

Comment: How about try to move "startAnimation();" from "onCreateView(...)" to "onResume(...)" ?

Comment: @chatea I try it , but it dosen't work.